# How to print multiple pages when table row count exceeds one page

Tags: java

I have been searching for a solution for a few weeks now. I developed a desktop invoice application that will printout the items bought on an A4 paper printer after each transaction. It works fine when the list of items in the table is below 15, however if a customer bought up to 40 items, the printout will only reflect the first 15 items and the remaining items will be lost because the paper is set to print only one-page index. I can set the page index to print multiple pages, but I don't know how to implement it in my code since there are other things the application needs to print before printing the table content.

I have attached a sample code that prints only one page.

```
public static class MyPrintable implements Printable {
@Override
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, 
                int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {    
                int result = NO_SUCH_PAGE;    
                if (pageIndex == 0) {                    
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;                    
                             
                double width = pageFormat.getImageableWidth();
                double height = pageFormat.getImageableHeight();    
                g2d.translate((int) pageFormat.getImageableX(),(int) pageFormat.getImageableY()); 
                Font font = new Font("Monospaced",Font.PLAIN,7);       
                g2d.setFont(font);
                   
                
                try {
            /*
                     * Draw Image*
                       assume that printing reciept has logo on top 
                     * that logo image is in .gif format .png also support
                     * image resolution is width 100px and height 50px
                     * image located in root--->image folder 
                     */
                                int x=100 ;                       //print start at 100 on x axies
                                int y=10;                         //print start at 10 on y axies
                                int imagewidth=100;
                                int imageheight=50;
                      BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/image/logo.gif"));
                      g2d.drawImage(read,x,y,imagewidth,imageheight,null);         //draw image
                      g2d.drawLine(10, y+60, 180, y+60);                          //draw line
                             } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        try{
        /*Draw Header*/
                int y=80;
              g2d.drawString("ABC Shopping Complex", 40,y);  
              g2d.drawString("CopyWrite 2009-2014", 50,y+10);  //shift a line by adding 10 to y value
              g2d.drawString(now(), 10, y+20);                                //print date
              g2d.drawString("Cashier : admin", 10, y+30);  
                
              /*Draw Colums*/
                  g2d.drawLine(10, y+40, 180, y+40);
                  g2d.drawString(title[0], 10 ,y+50);
                  g2d.drawString(title[1], 50 ,y+50);
                  g2d.drawString(title[2], 100 ,y+50);
                  g2d.drawString(title[3], 150 ,y+50);
                  g2d.drawLine(10, y+60, 180, y+60);
               
              int cH = 0;
              TableModel mod = itemsTable.getModel();
                    
              for(int i = 0;i < mod.getRowCount() ; i++){
                    /*Assume that all parameters are in string data type for this situation
                             * All other premetive data types are accepted.
                            */
                    String itemid = mod.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
                    String itemname = mod.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
                    String price = mod.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
                    String quantity = mod.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
                    
                    cH = (y+70) + (10*i);                             //shifting drawing line
                    
                    g2d.drawString(itemid, 0, cH);
                    g2d.drawString(itemname,50, cH);
                    g2d.drawString(price , 100, cH);
                    g2d.drawString(quantity , 150, cH);
                          
                }
                g2d.drawString("TOTAL DUE: ",10, cH+70);
                g2d.drawString("\u20A6"+decimalFormat.format(sumTotal),500, cH+70);
                    
                g2d.drawString("Payment Mode: ",20, cH+100);
                g2d.drawString(mode,500, cH+100);

                /*Footer*/
                font = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,16) ;                  //changed font size
                g2d.setFont(font);
                    g2d.drawString("Thank You Come Again",30, cH+10);
                                                                             //end of the reciept
        }
        catch(Exception r){
          r.printStackTrace();
        }

                result = PAGE_EXISTS;    
            }    
            return result;    
     }
  }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code.  I had to remove all the static references to get it top compile.  This is my best guess as to how to print multiple pages.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class PrintTest {

    private double sumTotal;
    
    private int itemsTableRow;
    
    private JTable itemsTable;

    private NumberFormat decimalFormat;

    private String mode;

    private String[] title;

    private TableModel tableModel;

    public class MyPrintable implements Printable {
        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) 
                throws PrinterException {
            int result = NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            g2d.translate((int) pageFormat.getImageableX(), 
                    (int) pageFormat.getImageableY());
            Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 7);
            g2d.setFont(font);
            
            if (pageIndex == 0) {
                drawImage(g2d);
                try {
                    /* Draw Header */
                    int y = 80;
                    printHeader(g2d, y);

                    int cH = 0;
                    tableModel = itemsTable.getModel();
                    itemsTableRow = Math.min(15, tableModel.getRowCount());

                    cH = printDetailLines(g2d, tableModel, 0, itemsTableRow, y, cH);
                    if (itemsTableRow >= tableModel.getRowCount()) {
                        printTotal(g2d, cH);
                    }
                    // end of the receipt
                    result = PAGE_EXISTS;
                
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            
            } else {
                if (itemsTableRow < tableModel.getRowCount()) {
                    int y = 0; // Assuming no header on subsequent pages
                    int start = itemsTableRow;
                    int end = start + 40;   // The number is how many rows fir on the second page
                    end = Math.min(end, tableModel.getRowCount());
                    int cH = 0;
                    cH = printDetailLines(g2d, tableModel, start, end, y, cH);
                    if (itemsTableRow >= tableModel.getRowCount()) {
                        printTotal(g2d, cH);
                    }
                    itemsTableRow = end;
                    
                    result = PAGE_EXISTS;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private void drawImage(Graphics2D g2d) {
            try {
                /*
                 * Draw Image* assume that printing reciept has logo on top that logo image is
                 * in .gif format .png also support image resolution is width 100px and height
                 * 50px image located in root--->image folder
                 */
                int x = 100; // print start at 100 on x axies
                int y = 10; // print start at 10 on y axies
                int imagewidth = 100;
                int imageheight = 50;
                BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/image/logo.gif"));
                g2d.drawImage(read, x, y, imagewidth, imageheight, null); // draw image
                g2d.drawLine(10, y + 60, 180, y + 60); // draw line
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void printHeader(Graphics2D g2d, int y) {
            g2d.drawString("ABC Shopping Complex", 40, y);
            g2d.drawString("CopyWrite 2009-2014", 50, y + 10); // shift a line by adding 10 to y value
            g2d.drawString(now(), 10, y+20);                                //print date
            g2d.drawString("Cashier : admin", 10, y + 30);

            /* Draw Colums */
            g2d.drawLine(10, y + 40, 180, y + 40);
            g2d.drawString(title[0], 10, y + 50);
            g2d.drawString(title[1], 50, y + 50);
            g2d.drawString(title[2], 100, y + 50);
            g2d.drawString(title[3], 150, y + 50);
            g2d.drawLine(10, y + 60, 180, y + 60);
        }

        private int printDetailLines(Graphics2D g2d, TableModel mod, 
                int start, int end, int y, int cH) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                /*
                 * Assume that all parameters are in string data type for this situation All
                 * other permeative data types are accepted.
                 */
                String itemid = mod.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
                String itemname = mod.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
                String price = mod.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
                String quantity = mod.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();

                cH = (y + 70) + (10 * i); // shifting drawing line

                g2d.drawString(itemid, 0, cH);
                g2d.drawString(itemname, 50, cH);
                g2d.drawString(price, 100, cH);
                g2d.drawString(quantity, 150, cH);

            }
            return cH;
        }

        private void printTotal(Graphics2D g2d, int cH) {
            Font font;
            g2d.drawString("TOTAL DUE: ", 10, cH + 70);
            g2d.drawString("\u20A6" + decimalFormat.format(sumTotal), 500, cH + 70);

            g2d.drawString("Payment Mode: ", 20, cH + 100);
            g2d.drawString(mode, 500, cH + 100);

            /* Footer */
            font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16); // changed font size
            g2d.setFont(font);
            g2d.drawString("Thank You Come Again", 30, cH + 10);
        }
        
        private String now() {
            return "";
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. I will check it and get back to you. Thank you once again.

Comment: Thanks once again for your quick response. I have implemented your idea but it only prints the first page and leaves the rest. I just feel there are little things I am missing to get the desired result. Please assist me if you come up with a better idea.